# Add two Facebook log in buttons in same Android app - two activities

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I have two activities that needs to use the Facebook login buttons. I have done it for one activity (as FaceBook developer site explains) already and its working. when I do the to second activity user cant login using the second button.

If any one have came across the same scenario, please kind to share the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please add some more information to your post, like your code, and more on how the buttons are placed? And also, why can't you just sign the user in with one button, and not two?

Comment: this shouldn't be a problem. i had this scenario twice. maybe you didn't implement the fb session right. if you login on first activity you should see a logout in the second.. but therefore (like hichris recommended) you need to add more code...

Comment: @longilong yeah, That was it, Thanks. put it as the answer so I can award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this shouldn't be a problem. i had this scenario twice. maybe you didn't implement the fb session right. if you login on first activity you should see a logout in the second.. but therefore (like hichris recommended) you need to add more code..